# how to adjust CSS image on mobile device while maintaining the aspect ratio

Tags: css, responsive-design

our site is not responsive, and one of the requirement is to render the images on mobile devices so they fit the screen and we are running into a problem, becasue different sized images are uploaded to a web page

And this is what our CSS code looks like

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {


            .article-body div img:not(.logoOP){
               width: 320px !important;
               height: 214px !important;
            }
}
```

So this works fine for 600 X 400 images, because the aspect ratio is the same. However, when we have a different size images, say 400X578, the above CSS code won't work and the images look really stretched and distorted.

What is a good solution here, since I am no front end Dev.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: best way is to use % for width and set the height to auto (so that it keeps aspect ratio.

Comment: add `height: auto;` to img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your CSS to the following:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {

        .article-body div img:not(.logoOP){
           width: 320px !important;
           height: auto;
        }
}
```

This will allow you to specify the width of the image and the height will automatically adjust itself proportional to the width.

Comment: I put the !important attribute for height:auto as well. That addressed the problem